# calling api call from Angular, returns a status 403

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, api

I have a angular 8 application.

And I have a api call. Like this:

```
  getWelcomePopupsByParticipant(): Observable<WelcomePopup> {
    return this.get('/api/medical/organisation/1/Project/participant/{patientUUID}/participant-welcomepopups');
  }
```

```
  get(route: string, responseType: RespType = 'json', fullResponse: boolean = false, params = null): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke('GET', route, null, responseType, fullResponse, true, params);
  }
```

And now I try to call that api method in a file: FirstViewModalComponent.ts, like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateScreenDimensions();
    const test =  this.healthApiService.getWelcomePopupsByParticipant().subscribe((welcomPopup: WelcomePopup) => {

      console.log('WelcomePopup', welcomPopup);

    });

  }
```

but when I go to that page. I get this error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden", url: "http://localhost:50762/api/medical/organisation/1/…-4373-ba22-3ee280c1c45a/participant-welcomepopups", ok: false, …}
error: null
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:50762/api/medical/organisation/1/Project/participant/32324147-aad8-4373-ba22-3ee280c1c45a/participant-welcomepopups: 403 Forbidden"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
url: "http://localhost:50762/api/medical/organisation/1/Project/participant/32324147-aad8-4373-ba22-3ee280c1c45a/participant-welcomepopups"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

But I am also using swagger. and in there it works fine.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Oke,

so this is the backend:

```
 [HttpGet("participant/{participantId}/participant-welcomepopups")]
        [Authorize(AuthorizationPolicies.ParticipantResource)]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WelcomePopupDto>> GetWelcomePopupsByParticipant(Guid participantId, int organisationId)
        {
            //get de projects where the participant is participating
            List<Guid> projectsIds = await _patientDbContext.ProjectParticipants
                .Where(i => i.ParticipantId == participantId)
                .Select(i => i.ProjectId).ToListAsync();

            return _medicalDbContext.Projects
                .Where(i => projectsIds.Contains(i.ProjectId) && i.OrganisationId == organisationId && i.ProjectId != _appSettings.DefaultProjectId)
                .Select(i => i.ToWelcomeDto());
        }
```

And yes, it is a bearer token:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken = this.auth.getAccessToken();

    if (accessToken != null) {
      const duplicate = request.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer  ${accessToken}` }
      });
      return next.handle(duplicate);
    } else {
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap(
          _ => {},
          error => {
            if (
              error instanceof HttpErrorResponse &&
              error.status === 503 &&
              error.url.startsWith(environment.ApiOrigin)
            ) {
              // Logout when the backend api is under maintenance.
              // The indentity server will show the under maintenance page.
              this.auth.requestLogout();
            }
          }
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: A 403 means there is an error with authorization. Does the API require some sort of login? If so, you are most likely missing to send a auth-token along the request.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Because in Swagger I login in as admin. but then I do the get method:/api/medical/organisation/{organisationId}/Project/participant/{participantId}/participant-welcomepopups. And fill in for the other participantID:32324147-AAD8-4373-BA22-3EE280C1C45A and organisation = 1. And that works

Comment: Well in that case - depending on what kind of authentication the api requires - you'll have to implement that first and then send the auth-token along with the request.

Comment: Oke, but what exactly do you mean?

Comment: He can't answer because he doesn't know what type of authorization you are using.  Are you using Bearer Tokens?   Are you using SAML?   Regardless, you will need to add a header to your call, before it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to send `withCredentials` in your headers, along with your API token

For example:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'
  }),
 withCredentials: true
};
```

Then add the httpOptions to your API call

```
myCall() {
  return this.http.get('https://www.example.com/api',httpOptions);
}
```

For reference: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest